# Stream microphone input to HTML5 using c#

Tags: c#, html, audio, streaming

I want to capture an audio source such as mic or sound card using c# and stream it to a remote HTML5 application preferably using the HTML5 "Audio" tag.
I don't want to use browser plugins (such as VLC or Flash) 
I need the latency to be minimal. 
Thanks!

Uzi